# How do I output value from a checked checkbox?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I am using WordPress.
I have a loop which runs a query from a database ...
I have a:

```
 <form action="" method="post"> ...

 function create(){
      $sql = Select.... 
      $res  = $wpdb->get_results($sql);

    foreach($res as $row)
      {
            $idy = $row->id;

            //hyperlink
            echo '<a href="'.get_admin_url().'post.php?post='.$pid.'&action=edit&remove_bid=1#project_bids">'.__('Remove Winner','ProjectTheme').'</a>';


            //checkbox
            echo '<input type="checkbox" name="postid" value="$idy" checked>';          
      }
```

This is the code for adding the value into a checkbox, that is working fine.

The problem is that if a user checks a checkbox, and clicks on a hyperlink which locates to:

```
 if(isset($_GET['remove_bid']))
     {
        $id = $_POST['postid'];
        echo $id;
         // This part does not identify a checked checkbox, and it does not output any value
     }
   }//end function
```

Comment: you need to wrap your input in `<form action="" method="post">` to and submit the form to get value as `$_POST['postid']`

Comment: Sorry I already have a <form action "" method="post">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
>         echo '<a href="'.get_admin_url().'post.php?post='.$pid.'&action=edit&remove_bid=1#project_bids">'.__('Remove Winner','ProjectTheme').'</a>';
> ```

You are passing you argument as "post" and you are waiting for "postid"

You should have something like this:

> ```
>         echo '<a href="'.get_admin_url().'post.php?postid='.$pid.'&action=edit&remove_bid=1#project_bids">'.__('Remove Winner','ProjectTheme').'</a>';
> ```

Comment: Thanks dude! Just needed to add another argument... postid='.$id.'&post='.$pid.'